# the better way to trnascode the audio and video files in java?

Tags: java, audio, video, transcoding

i am looking for api's for trans-coding the audio video files in java,

i am currently trying out the xuggler project but can't done much with this need some recommendation which will be suitable for my requirements

1. audio video trans-coding
2. bitrate and frame rate management for media files
3. cut and save the parts of audio and video
4. burn the files to cd dvd

the above operations i need to do please guide which api's will help

currently i am looking an [vlcj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) and [handbreak](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) the open source projects.

help required

Comment: What you have are sufficient; add another one: [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) for Java in various flavors: http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php or http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: jffmpeg will be a risky option as there is no activity on it since 2006 and vlcj is not good for long processes is there any other option which can given me both control and power?

Comment: How long do you expect to run your streaming server? I have tested VLCJ 1.2.0 (with libVLC 1.1.11 engine) before; it can run more than 1 day.